# Como extraigo ciertas filas de mi csv?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, csv

Necesito extraer de mi data frame la fila 3600 y que así vaya iterando y que lo imprima en otro data frame, por ejemplo que extraiga la fila 3600-7200-10800-etc y los imprima en otro csv

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import csv

all_files = glob.glob("C:/Users/ep_irojaso/Desktop/PROGRAMA DESEMPEÑO/saturnmensual/*.csv")

file_list = []
for f in (all_files):   
    data = pd.read_csv(f,usecols=["t","f"])

    file_list.append(data)
    
df.to_csv(f'C:/Users/ep_irojaso/Desktop/PROGRAMA DESEMPEÑO/Saturn2/{os.path.basename(f).split(".")[0]}_ext.csv')
```

Comment: `df.iloc[3600:7200].to_csv("fichero_de_salida.csv")`

Comment: Para que siga aumentado cada 3600 debo hacer un ciclo for dentro de esta linea de codigo?

Comment: No me funciona esa linea de codigo ya que solo necesito que extraiga la fila 3600,7200,10800 ,no de 3600 a 7200

Comment: Ah, entendí mal. Quizás entonces `df.iloc[3600::3600].to_csv("fichero_de_salida.csv")` ?

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, soluciono mi problema

Comment: Aunque la solución era una sola línea, he decidido escribirla en forma de respuesta para explicarla mejor y para que quede como referencia para futuras consultas similares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas implementa las funciones para acceder a elementos de un dataframe a través de un índice, mediante la propiedad `df.iloc[]`. El índice que se pasa en los corchetes se refiere al número de la fila (independientemente del índice que tenga el dataframe).

Esta propiedad implementa además la sintaxis de los *slices* lo que significa que puedes pasarle algo con la estructura `[inicio:fin:paso]` igual que a las listas python, y te extraerá un subconjunto de las filas seleccionadas, comenzando por la que tiene índice `inicio`, avanzando de `paso` en paso y terminando cuando llega a la fila de índice `fin` o superior.

Si omites `inicio` comenzará en el índice 0. Si omites `fin` llegará hasta la última fila. Si omites `paso`, irá de uno en uno.

Así pues, en tu caso, ya que quieres empezar en la fila 3600 y llegar hasta el final avanzando de 3600 en 3600 la sintaxis será:

```
df.iloc[3600::3600]
```

Una vez seleccionadas esas filas puedes hacer con ellas lo que precises. Entre otras cosas puedes volcarlas a csv

```
df.iloc[3600::3600].to_csv("nombre_del_fichero.csv")
```

**Nota**. La propiedad `.iloc[]` admite también dos slices, separados por una coma, por ejemplo: `df.iloc[3600::3600,2:5]`. En este caso el primer slice selecciona las filas y el segundo selecciona las columnas. En este ejemplo se extraerían las columnas en posiciones 2, 3 y 4 (siendo la primera columna la 0). Si quieres mostrar todas las filas para ciertas columnas puedes usar `df.iloc[:,2:5]` por ejemplo. El primer slice `:` selecciona todas las filas (pues no se ha especificado ni inicio ni fin ni paso) y el segundo slice `2:5` seleccionaría las columnas en posición 2, 3 y 4.